# javascript Date.parse() parsing non-dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to loop through an array and work out which items are dates. To do this I am running the values through Date.parse(value), which is supposed to only parse valid dates.

The problem is that this string is parsed as a date

```
"Test Title 1"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonhobbs/LHeQ8/

This tells me that you can't trust Date.parse at all but I don't know of an alternatve. I've tried the moment.js library and that gives me the same thing as it uses Date.parse() internally.

Comment: hou need to validate date schemes yourself before parsing them.

Comment: This is because your string contains a number.

Comment: Well yes, I know it contains a number, but it's not a date, and other strings with numbers are not parsed by Date.parse(), so the only thing I can conclude is that Date.parse() is happy to parse things that aren't dates, so is not reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to use a regex instead.